# Force drop an MSSQL login?

Tags: sql-server, authentication

I can't drop a newly created login, as the server keeps throwing the "Could not drop login '(..)' as the user is currently logged in. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 15434)".

The login was created a few minutes earlier and used once from a .NET web app, the web app has been shut down (the whole IIS server is stopped), the SQL server has been restarted several times and the session table is empty.

What could be causing the server to still think the user is logged in, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Might this be your own query window? Even if you cut your SSMS a single window can keep its connetion...

Comment: Yes, that was it. Thank you!

Comment: Sure. I just wanted to add my details (about the disconnecting and reconnecting), but it's your answer so go ahead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be aware, that each window of your SQL Server Management Studio keeps its own connection open.

You are in conflict with your own SSMS query window...

Just as a little story:

I once had a query prepared for a test system. When everything was running fine I disconnected the SSMS server pane from the test system and re-connected it to the identical productive system. As the database's name was the same I just executed the file and was very surprised, that I got errors like "object already exists...". It took me a while to find, that the open query was still running against the test system. There is no obvious hint to reflect this...

Answer (score 0):

(Thanks to Shnugo's comment for the solution)

Apparently the SQL Server Management Studio is what kept the user logged in, even though I had disconnected and re-connected with my Windows username. A simple SSMS restart solved the problem.